# Yii2: Submit and validate a form by using a button outside the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form-submit, yii2

I'm having a problem when submitting and validating a form by using a button outside the form, using Yii2.

This is my case:

I have a form (**myForm**) and a submit button (**myButton**) inside of that form. When I click the myButton the validation is performed and if validation fails, then the submit is not performed. This is expected, of course, and it works.

However, What I really want is to submit **myForm** by clicking on **myButton** which is outside the form element. To acomplish this I simply call jQuery('myForm').submit(), and the submit works.

The problem I face with this last scenario, is that the validation fails but the form is yet submitted, which is not expected.

**How can I submit a form with a button outside the form, and make the validation work too?**

This is my view:

```
<?php

    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL,
            'options' => ['class' => 'main-task-form']
        ]);

    echo Form::widget([
            'model' => $modelData,
            'form' => $form,
            'columns' => 2,
            'attributes' => [
                'closeDate' => [
                        'type'=> 'widget',
                        'widgetClass'=> DatePicker::className(),
                        'options'=>[
                            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'autoclose' => true,
                                'language' => 'es',
                                'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                                'todayBtn' => 'linked',
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                'descriptionClose' => [
                    'type'=>'textarea', 
                    'options' => [
                        'rows' => 3,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
?>



<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
<!-- Form Ends Here -->


<!-- Submit Button Outside Form -->
<?= Html::button('Completar Tarea', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-task-form']) ?>
```

And this is the Javascript code to tell the button outside the form, to trigger the submit:

```
function assignCompleteButtonToTaskForm ()
{

    var completeButton = jQuery ('button.btn-task-form')[0];
    var mainTaskForm = jQuery ('form.main-task-form')[0];

    completeButton.onclick = function (e) {
        mainTaskForm.submit ();
    }
}
```

Any idea about this?

Also, how can I trigger directly the validation process before perform the submit manually? Maybe that will help me to control the submit process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, combining some of your previous answers. Now I'm able to trigger form validation and request a confirmation correctly as expected initially. [See the final code](https://gist.github.com/jonvargas/9b887b465e272b38ccdf). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You can also manually trigger the validation of the form in Yii way, with following javascript code

```
$('#form-id').yiiActiveForm('submitForm');
```

This will validate the form and returns `true` if there are no validation errors otherwise `false`.

So you can combine this and form submit calls to achieve desired behaviour.

Also, sometimes its good idea to dive into the code and see how things are working internally, you can see how yii is handling most of its active form stuff in frontend in [yii.activeForm.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js), Im sure you won't regret it.

Comment: `submitForm` does NOT submit the form. It triggers the "on submit"-validation and returns a boolean to indicate whether it is safe to actual do the submission.

Comment: @Blizz True, thanks for correction, I have updated the answer. Though not sure anymore if its the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, although the submitForm function is called several times by itself (don't know why), the hint it works, except for something: If I want to display a confirm dialog, then the confirm dialog will display twice or more, since sometimes Yii's submitForm function returns false and until the last invoke it returns true. See video at: youtu.be/kyzZt-3E1J4 . 

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just do it by using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // Set Button ID or class replacing # to .  
    $("#you_button_id").on('click', function(event){
         // When you click on this button don't do any thing.
         event.preventDefault();
         // Set form ID and submit that form
         $("#your_form_id").submit();
    });
})
```

try if it works.

Comment: Yes this works, the submit works as expected. The problem I am now having is that the submit continues even when the validation fails. I think this will work for most non-yii developers.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have the same situation in my code and I use a combination of both other answers:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $form = $('#form_id");
   $form.on('submit', function(e) {
      return $form.yiiActiveForm('submitForm');
   }); 

   $('#submit_button_id").on('click', function() { 
      $form.submit();
   });
});
```

The reason you have to call `submitForm` yourself (if you want to validate once more before submit) is because the default Yii2 implementation binds the call of this function to submit inputs within the form. This means it won't be called for an external trigger.

Comment: This is weird, when debugging this code , the call to Yii's "submitForm" happens more than once returning false, and it's until the last call that it returns true, so I can't use that function to determine if to do the actual submit.

Comment: Well, although the submitForm function is called several times by itself, it works, except for something: If I want to display a confirm dialog, then the confirm dialog will display twice or more, since sometimes Yii's submitForm function returns false and sometimes true. See video at:

http://youtu.be/kyzZt-3E1J4

Any idea?